# How can I include multiple ranges to text to columns via VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there anyway to combine the following code to include the required columns in order for them to text to column or do I need to leave it as is? I have multiple ranges including U2, V2, N2, X2, AB2, & Z2

```
Set sh = Worksheets("Data")
With sh
Set rng = .[U2]
Set rng = .Range(rng, .Cells(.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp))

    rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Set rng = .[V2]
Set rng = .Range(rng, .Cells(.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp))

    rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Set rng = .[N2]
Set rng = .Range(rng, .Cells(.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp))

    rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Set rng = .[X2]
Set rng = .Range(rng, .Cells(.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp))

    rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Set rng = .[AB2]
Set rng = .Range(rng, .Cells(.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp))

    rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Set rng = .[Z2]
Set rng = .Range(rng, .Cells(.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp))

    rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine several ranges like this:

```
Set rng1 = Range("U2:U2")
Set rng2 = Range("V2:V2")
'and so on..
Set yourBigNewRange = Union(rng1, rng2, ... )
```

You can work with this new range exactly the same way you would work with any other range.